# how to communicate server and client with different version of Netty?

Tags: netty

I have struggled server client communication with Netty.

My Question is

how to communicate server and client with different version of Netty?

Netty Client version is 3.x.x.
      Server version is 4.0.21

but Sever and client cannot communicate.

I want to show the code but this is governmental project so i could not post it.

Thanks.

Comment: Post an example that's similar to what you want to do, but is generic.

Comment: Use a common protocol to communicate between client-server. Use encoders/decoders to do the conversion between protocols.

Comment: With 4.x client version same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, Netty is just a framework which handles the connection management (*) and passes the incoming data to decoder/encoder handlers provided by you. So as long as the your decoders/encoders do translate from/to the same binary protocol you can use any combination of client and server. You don't actually need to use netty at all.

(*) Netty is of course more than that, it provides out of the box some protocols already implemented, abstract handlers etc but still they are based on some existing protocol specification and are not specific to Netty version.